# Laravel Datatables with custom date range filter server-side processing

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, laravel, datatables

I have a datatables in my system which I want to optimize. I have Laravel and jQuery Datatables. My problem is I want to optimize the rendering of data if my data grid needs to have custom filter before drawing any data. In my other Datatables I have data grid which will pull data on page load which is fine and I can do server-side processing by just following this guide:

http://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/basic

However what if I have 3 filters like `From Date, To Date, Agent Name` I can make it work but my concern is my code is writing the data client side upon getting ajax response which will take time if I have very huge data set. My current code is:

```
$("#FormListBtn").click(function() {
   var table = $('#FormList').DataTable();
    $.ajax({
    url: "form-list",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {"from" : $("#datePickerFrom").val(), "to" :  $("#datePickerTo").val(), "agent_id" :  $("#agent_id").val()},
    success: function(result){
    var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(myObj, function(key,value) {
            var t = $('#FormList').DataTable();
            t.row.add( [
                value.id,
                value.calldatetime,
                value.survey,
                value.agent,
                value.campaign,
                value.name,
                value.phone,
                value.average_score,
                "<a class='btn btn-small btn-info' href='<?php echo URL::to('form').'/';?>"+value.id+"/edit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></a>",
                "<form method='POST' action='<?php echo URL::to('form').'/';?>"+value.id+"' accept-charset='UTF-8' class='pull-left' >"+
                "<input name='_method' type='hidden' value='DELETE'>"+
                "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' aria-hidden='true'></span></button>"+"</form>",

            ] ).draw();
        });
    }}); 
});
```

As you can see I am writting the rows on a loop which will take time in very huge data. Is there another way to make it faster?

The process is: User will select date range and agent name for the filter then clicks submit then generate the table.

My Controller

```
public function getFormList()
{
    $from = Input::get("from");
    $to   = Input::get("to");
    $agent_id   = Input::get("agent_id");

    if($agent_id != '')
    {
        $data2 = DB::table('forms')
        ->join('agents', 'agents.id', '=', 'forms.agent_id')
        ->join('campaigns', 'campaigns.id', '=', 'forms.campaign_id')
        ->join('surveys', 'surveys.id', '=', 'forms.survey_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'forms.evaluatedby_id')
        ->select(
            'forms.id', 
            'forms.calldatetime', 
            'forms.phone', 
            'forms.calldatetime', 
            'forms.average_score', 
            'forms.auto_fail', 
            'forms.yes_count', 
            'forms.no_count', 
            'forms.na_count', 
            'users.name', 
            'agents.name as agent', 
            'campaigns.name as campaign',
            'surveys.name as survey'
            )
        ->where('calldatetime', '>=', $from)
        ->where('calldatetime', '<=', $to)
        ->where('forms.agent_id', '=', $agent_id)
        ->get();
        return json_encode($data2);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = DB::table('forms')
        ->join('agents', 'agents.id', '=', 'forms.agent_id')
        ->join('campaigns', 'campaigns.id', '=', 'forms.campaign_id')
        ->join('surveys', 'surveys.id', '=', 'forms.survey_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'forms.evaluatedby_id')
        ->select(
            'forms.id', 
            'forms.calldatetime', 
            'forms.phone', 
            'forms.calldatetime', 
            'forms.average_score', 
            'forms.auto_fail', 
            'forms.yes_count', 
            'forms.no_count', 
            'forms.na_count', 
            'users.name', 
            'agents.name as agent', 
            'campaigns.name as campaign',
            'surveys.name as survey'
            )
        ->where('calldatetime', '>=', $from)
        ->where('calldatetime', '<=', $to)
        ->get();
        return json_encode($data);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is your concern. even if your dataset is large, you, should not load them all at once in your grid. You should look into pagination options for your datatable plugin I am referring to server side pagination. That way you will only be loading 10-20 records at once,

Comment: @Ankit  Hi. Thanks. I have already done that in my other data grid which dont have filters and will appear on page load, Datatables has api to do server side pagination. What I want to do is just load the data in a server side code not in client code (which i am currently doing) in the my post.

Comment: Ok.. Then you can your server side function return a view instead of json. in you view you can create the table markup and then in your ajax success method you just have to replace the content (  ('#FormList').html(responseHtml)) and initialize the data table on it.. if this is what you mean by loading the data server side.